# How do I solve the error Public key for jenkins-2.387.2-1.1.noarch.rpm is not installed when I run yum update for jenkins installation for the AWS EC2

Tags: linux, jenkins, amazon-ec2, devops, jenkins-plugins

let me know how to solve this problem

How do I solve the error Public key for jenkins-2.387.2-1.1.noarch.rpm is not installed when I run yum update for jenkins installation for the AWS EC2

i have tried this:-
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11 -y
yum install git maven jenkins -y
i was expecting this:-
systemctl start jenkins.service

but unfortunately service is not getting start

Answer (score 26):

The repository signing key [has just changed](https://community.jenkins.io/t/new-linux-repository-signing-keys-for-jenkins-2-397-and-2-387-2/6509). Fix the `rpm --import` to

```
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key
```

This is also updated in the [installation instructions](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/#long-term-support-release-3).

Comment: Thanks! That works for me. I'm in RHEL 8.7

Comment: Its 2024 its still working for me